# Why does changing subsite nginx vhost file to use php8.1 result in /core/install.php for an already installed site?

Tags: multi-sites

I'm trying to get the three sites of a multisite installation to use php8, all three have existing vhost files. The root site will use php8 after updating the vhost config, but the subsites respond with /core/install.php. Here is the relevant vhost config for both

```
location / {
    # This is cool because no php is touched for static content
    # try_files $uri @rewrite;
    try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string; # For Drupal >= 7
    limit_req zone=one burst=5 nodelay;
}

# XML Sitemap support.
location = /sitemap.xml {
    # try_files $uri @rewrite;
    try_files $uri /index.php;
}

location @rewrite {
    # Some modules enforce no slash (/) at the end of the URL
    # Else this rewrite block wouldn't be needed (GlobalRedirect)
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
}

location ~ ^/sites/.*/private/ {
    return 403;
}

# Don't allow direct access to PHP files in the vendor directory.
location ~ /vendor/.*\.php$ {
    deny all;
    return 404;
}

# In Drupal 8, we must also match new paths where the '.php' appears in
# the middle, such as update.php/selection. The rule we use is strict,
# and only allows this pattern with the update.php front controller.
# This allows legacy path aliases in the form of
# blog/index.php/legacy-path to continue to route to Drupal nodes. If
# you do not have any paths like that, then you might prefer to use a
# laxer rule, such as:
#   location ~ \.php(/|$) {
# The laxer rule will continue to work if Drupal uses this new URL
# pattern with front controllers other than update.php in a future
# release.
location ~ '\.php$|^/update.php' {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
    # Security note: If you're running a version of PHP older than the
    # latest 5.3, you should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini.
    # See http://serverfault.com/q/627903/94922 for details.
    include fastcgi_params;
    # Block httpoxy attacks. See https://httpoxy.org/.
    fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
}

# For Drupal7 use /styles instead of /imagecache
location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ {
        try_files $uri @rewrite;
}

# PERFORMANCE : Set expires headers for static files and turn off logging.
location ~* ^.+\.(js|css|swf|xml|txt|ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
    access_log off; log_not_found off; expires 30d;
}
```

This is likely taken from [this source](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/drupal/). Each individual vhost file has a discrete `server_name` and the same `server_root`. I'm noticing now that I'm getting 302s from any request.

So, to summarize the change that I made that is now causing 302 responses for every request to the *subsites*, I changed this line in the location block above

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
```

to what is there now

```
include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
```

Comment: Hello. Would you please explain the problem in a little more detail? As written, the outlines of the issue are unclear.

Comment: @cilefen I've added some more info to my question, I hope that's a little more clear, the specific issue has been a little hard to explain.